# Android MPChart - how to update the stackLabel?

Tags: android, charts, mpandroidchart

I am using MPChart and have multiple charts for different tabs and therefore when switching tabs, the stacked barchart and its label should be refreshed.

### Code:

BarDataSet set1;

```
    if (chart_stacked.getData() != null && chart_stacked.getData().getDataSetCount() > 0)
    {
        set1 = (BarDataSet) chart_stacked.getData().getDataSetByIndex(0);
        set1.setValues(yVals1);
        chart_stacked.getData().notifyDataChanged();
        chart_stacked.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
    else
    {
        // set1 = new BarDataSet(yVals1, "Toilet Statistics");
        set1 = new BarDataSet(yVals1, "");
        set1.setDrawIcons(false);
        set1.setColors(getColors());

        if (chart_type.equals("feed"))
        {
            set1.setStackLabels(new String[]{"A", "B"});
        }
        if (chart_type.equals("pump"))
        {
            set1.setStackLabels(new String[]{"C", "D"});
        }

        ArrayList<IBarDataSet> dataSets = new ArrayList<IBarDataSet>();
        dataSets.add(set1);

        BarData data = new BarData(dataSets);
        data.setValueTextColor(Color.BLACK);

        chart_stacked.setData(data);
    }
    chart_stacked.invalidate();
    Utilities.custom_toast(Stat.this, "chart type = " + chart_type, "gone", "short");
```

### Question:

The toast at the end shows that when pressing different tabs, the variable `chart type` is updated successfully. the bars are updated. However, the stacklabel is still showing A and B instead of C and D when pressing to the C&D page.

How could the stacklabel be refreshed? Thank you.

Comment: i have problem like this, but i just only want to hide stacklabel. Did u solve it bro?

Answer (score 0):

Replace this:

```
chart_stacked.invalidate();
Utilities.custom_toast(Stat.this, "chart type = " + chart_type, "gone", 
"short");
```

with:

```
chart_stacked.notifyDataSetChanged();
chart_stacked.invalidate();
Utilities.custom_toast(Stat.this, "chart type = " + chart_type, "gone", "short");
```